# Last Column command overwriting existing cell intermittently vba

Tags: vba, excel

[Screenshot of what is happening here, for simplicity sake, I have changed the values to represent the columns that they rightfully belong in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiGcA.png)

I am working on a program where I need to copy and reorganize data from multiple worksheets into one master. One row per sheet. From columns G to R I will need to set up an if statement, so that if a value on the sheet is greater than 0  it will be copy/pasted to the next available column in it's row. For testing I have eliminated the if statement, so that I always get a result. The problem I am having is that on the first row of data the "B" column is being overwritten, subsequent rows work as expected. Any ideas as to why this could be happening?

```
    Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim LastR As Long
    Dim LastC As Long

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Delete the sheet "Master" if it exist
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Add a worksheet with the name "Master"
    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "Master"

    'loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the DestSh
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

            'Find the last row with data on the DestSh
            With ActiveSheet
            LastR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
            End With

            With ActiveSheet
            LastC = .Cells(LastR, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            End With                

            sh.Range("B2").Copy
            DestSh.Cells(LastR + 1, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues   'customer'
            DestSh.Cells(LastR + 1, "B").Value = ("Glass")            'Product"
            DestSh.Cells(LastR + 1, "C").Value = sh.Name              'Color Name
            sh.Range("H32").Copy
            DestSh.Cells(LastR + 1, "D").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues   'based on QTY'
            DestSh.Cells(LastR + 1, "E").Value = ("Liters")           'based on Units'
            DestSh.Cells(LastR + 1, "F").Value = ("Clear")           'Base'

            sh.Range("F13").Copy
            DestSh.Cells(LastR + 1, LastC + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues   'THIS IS THE LINE GIVING ME TROUBLE'

        End If
    Next

ExitTheSub:

    Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

    'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
    DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: This is after adding the function below end sub]

Comment: Can you put some screenshots as well? The code looks pretty ok actually.

Comment: I suspect it's your `ActiveSheet` that's the problem. If your `ActiveSheet` is the Newly added 'Master` sheet, you will always add the value to column B in the first instance because when you get the count of the column, its prior to you adding any data on the sheet so at this stage your count will be 1. Once you start adding the data, you will get the correct count of the column. Try getting the column and row count after you've added the values in the sheet. Also, as per @Vityata suggestion, I'd strongly suggest not to use `ActiveSheet`. Always qualify your sheets

Comment: @Zac I have attempted Vityata 's suggestion, but I am getting the same result.

Comment: My suggestion is different from Vityata's. I'm suggesting that you get your column count after you've added the values in the row. Only reason I quoted Vityata's answer was because I don't like using `ActiveSheet`. It can get you in trouble

Comment: The problem is that you are not looking for last column, but for last column in last row. This is pretty different.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `ActiveSheet` with `DestSh`, probably this is the reason for the problem:

```
'Find the last row with data on the DestSh
With DestSh
    LastR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
End With

With DestSh
    LastC = .Cells(LastR, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
```

---

In your case, `LastC = .Cells(LastR, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` does not return the last column in the parent worksheet, but the last column in row `LastR`. Try this for the real last column:

```
LastC = LastRow(DestSh)

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

And this is worth reading - https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Comment: Thank you, but it's still overwriting. I am adding a screen shot to the op now

Comment: I have replaced that "With statement" containing the definition for last c, with the code that you just posted and I'm getting "error 424 object required" debugging points to that block. Thank you for the help btw.

Comment: @hithenameisbj - take a better look at the code, there is some `.rng`, which is non defined. In general, see the edit.

Comment: That gives me  an "expected end sub" under the definition for lastc. If I attempt to run again without altering the code I get "for control variable already in use" pointing to "For Each sh In".

At this point, I am thinking of just setting a fixed paste location, and having it assign "0" values to the cells with an if statement, and deleting 0's with a separate code.

Comment: @hithenameisbj - the `LastC=LastRow(DestSh)` should be put on the place of `LastC = .Cells(LastR, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` in your code. Then, after the last `End Sub` of your code, write `Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _ ... etc`

Comment: No longer getting errors, but it is causing another odd shift in data. I've added a screenshot to the bottom of the original post to show what it is doing now.